# Creating a dynamic drag image with canvas and setDragImage

Tags: canvas, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

Apparently you can use and **image element** or a **canvas element** with HTML5's native drag and drop [setDragImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage). This overrides the native 'ghosted' image of what you're dragging.

However I can't seem to get it to work, does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
var canvas              = document.createElement('canvas');
    context             = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.height      = '100px';
    context.width       = '200px';
    context.fillStyle   = 'blue';
    context.font        = 'bold 16px Arial';
    context.fillText('hello world', 0, 16);
    context.fillRect(20, 10, 200, 100);

    console.log(canvas);
e.dataTransfer.setDragImage( canvas, 50,50 );
```

Also, I'm very surprised that I cannot use a div with `createElement()` I guess the div must already exist to use that as the drag image?

```
var dragIcon = document.createElement('div');
    dragIcon.style.cssText = 'width:200px;height:100px;background-color:red;';
```

Comment: For the first part of the question, canvas's context2d has no width nor height properties, you should set the canvas' one. But this should still work with your given code : https://jsfiddle.net/45k8z4kr/1/ At least it does in FF... There seems to be a bug in chrome, where you need to pass the dataURL as src of an image element : https://jsfiddle.net/76Lc1tas/

Comment: For the second part, the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-datatransfer-setdragimage) say that if the element argument is not an image, "set the drag data store bitmap to an image generated from the given element". Which will produce nothing for a non visible element. (Older specs were more clear and stated "image should be a visible node and the drag image will be created from this.")

Answer (score 0):

The Canvas element needs to be part of the DOM for some reason as mentioned in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790022/html5-draggable-setdragimage-doesnt-work-with-canvas-on-chrome).

Apply styling to the canvas so that it is not visible to the user. One way of doing so which would work for most use cases is

```
canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
canvas.style.left = '-100%';
canvas.style.zIndex = '-100';
```

Then append the Canvas element to the DOM.

```
document.body.append(canvas);
```